# Does this equation have a solution?

Tags: probability, integration, statistics

Suppose $Q:[0,1]^2\to R$ and $f,g:[0,1]\to R_+$ are  probability densities.

$$\int_{[0,1]}[P(x,y)-Q(x,y)]f(x)dx=C_1, \forall y$$

$$\int_{[0,1]}[Q(x,y)-P(x,y)]g(y)dy=C_2, \forall x$$

s.t. $$C_1>0,C_2>0$$
and
$$ 0\leq P(x,y)+Q(x,y)\leq 1, \forall (x,y)\in[0,1]$$,
The question is: does this equation have a solution for $Q$?

Thanks.

Comment: Certainly not if $C>1$.

Comment: Could it be possible to calculate the maximal C,without restricting the structure of Q?